# MySQL NOT IN function of array of data

Tags: php, mysql

This is my query. Using `WHERE IN` works normally in the MySQL GUI, however, when I run this query, it returns an empty result. I have checked them manually if the dates exist in the `events` table, and they really do.

```sql
SELECT * FROM venues v 
  LEFT JOIN reservations r ON v.venue_id = r.venue_id 
  LEFT JOIN events e ON e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id 
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('$dates')
```

`$dates` is just a string of dates (i.e., 11-11-2018, 11-12-2018).

Comment: `$dates` is variable right? then y did u give inside the quotes?

Comment: What is the datatype of column `date_of_use` ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: date_of_use is text

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the `$dates` string.

It should be formatted as `'11-11-2018', '11-12-2018'` i.e. each value should be enclosed in quotes to make `IN` query work.

Currently, your query looks like

```
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('11-11-2018, 11-12-2018');
```

which will search for rows with 2 dates instead of single dates.

Here's how a correct query would look like,

```
SELECT * FROM venues v 
JOIN reservations r ON v.venue_id = r.venue_id 
JOIN events e ON e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id 
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('11-11-2018', '11-12-2018')
```

**Update 1**

Based on your comment, you have to implode the array with `','`.

```
$dates = implode( "','", $date );
```

And then the below `WHERE` clause will work perfect,

```
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('$dates')
```

**Update 2**

If `events` and `reservations` tables are empty, then you need to use `LEFT JOIN` and fetch rows where date_of_use `IS NULL`

```
SELECT * FROM venues v 
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON v.venue_id = r.venue_id 
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id 
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('$dates')
OR e.date_of_use IS NULL
```

Comment: `$start = new DateTime($init->post('start'));`
 `$end = new DateTime($init->post('end'));`
 `$date = array();`
 
 `if($start == $end){`
  `$date[] = $start->format('m-d-Y');`
 `} else{`
  `$period = new DatePeriod(`
       `$start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end`
       
  `);`

  `foreach($period as $key => $value){`
   `$date[] = $value->format('m-d-Y');`
  `}`
 `}`

 `$dates = implode( ',', $date );`

Comment: sorry, how can i edit this comment so it would look like its properly indented?

Comment: You can't format comments section. Np, have updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: I have now updated my code sir, however, it still shows an empty array. So my events table is empty but my venues table is not.

Comment: Check Update 2.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM venues v JOIN reservations r ON v.venue_id = r.venue_id LEFT JOIN events e ON e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('11-12-2018','11-13-2018') OR e.date_of_use IS NULL` I have tried and still shows an empty object sir.

Comment: Does reservation table has any entry?

Comment: No sir, all is empty except venues. Thus, all venues are available

Comment: In that case, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` on reservations table too. Check Update 2. Also, study `MySQL JOINS` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Comment: Done sir but it wont show up because it says that i should have 15+ reputations.

Answer (score 0):

If `$dates` variable as you say, is a string with comma separated dates "11-11-2018, 11-12-2018" the query becomes:

```
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('11-11-2018, 11-12-2018')
```

whereas the right format would be:

```
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('2018-11-11', '2018-11-12')
```

i.e. each date should be intoduced separately inside `IN` and the date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

To handle also the case where events do not exists for a venue:

```
SELECT * FROM venues v 
JOIN reservations r ON v.venue_id = r.venue_id 
LEFT JOIN events e ON e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id 
  AND (e.date_of_use IS NULL OR e.date_of_use NOT IN ('2018-11-11', '2018-11-12'))
```

Comment: i see but the events table sir is empty so i was hoping to see all venues available. However, it shows an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You can structure your array in php like this:

```
<?php
$DateArray=array();
$DateArray=["11-11-2018", "12-11-2018","11-11-2018", "11-12-2018"];

$Dates='(';
foreach ($DateArray as $key => $value) 
{   $Dates=$Dates." ".$value.",";       }

$Dates=rtrim($Dates,",");
$Dates=$Dates.")"; // contains ( 11-11-2018, 12-11-2018, 11-11-2018, 11-12-2018)
?>
```

And append the php variable like this:

```
SELECT * FROM venues v, reservations r, events e
WHERE v.venue_id = r.venue_id 
AND e.reservation_id = r.reservation_id AND e.date_of_use NOT IN .$Dates;
```

Comment: The dates are okay sir, however i cannot achieve to show all venues that are available or venues whose reservation date is not in the events.date_of_use

Comment: Ok try the query which i have written Hardcode the dates. Is it fetching records?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use simplfy your query for debug?

Something like

```
SELECT * FROM events e 
WHERE e.date_of_use NOT IN ('11-11-2018', '11-12-2018')
```

Replace dates array using implode function in PHP.

Also you would better use date type rather than text.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format